# How to install RabbitMq silent

Tags: windows, powershell, rabbitmq

I am trying to create one Octopus step that downloads, installs and configures rabbitmq on Windows.

I have tried the following (excluding the download code)

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\otp_win64_19.0.exe" -ArgumentList '/S' -Wait  
Start-Process 'c:\temp\rabbitmq-server-3.6.5.exe' '/S' -Wait
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmq-plugins.bat' 'enable rabbitmq_management' -Wait
```

This usually hangs in the second step (rabbitmq install) and never completes. 
Have anyone done this successfully?

Comment: Might be related? https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/264

Comment: No I don't think so since I am doing a clean install in my case

Answer (score 10):

I resolved with following command:

```
$proc = Start-Process 'c:\temp\rabbitmq-server-3.6.5.exe' '/S' -Wait:$false -Passthru

Wait-Process -Id $proc.Id
```

Comment: You're a life saver.